# knockout - array of objects and view, right way?

Tags: knockout.js

I have an array of objects in which each object represents data for a view view. I want to initiate a set of properties for each of the objects so that I can easily add onto the objects from one function. The way I am doing this is like so.

```
var createViewProperties = function () {
        return {
            rightContentVisibility: ko.observable(true) // normally false, true for testing
        };
    };

var data= [
   {
     headline: "Are you interested in helping others?",
     viewProperties: new createViewProperties(),
   },
   {
     headline: "This is a second modal view",
     viewProperties: new createViewProperties(),
   }
];
```

I then find the proper object that I want to display and update the object of the view model. In the HTML, I paint the view like so.

```
<div data-bind="with: currentView">
     <div data-bind="css: $data.headline" class="cover-img"></div>
     <div data-bind="$data.viewProperties.rightContentVisibility"></div>
</div>
```

However the browser has .rightContentVisibility as undefined, am I not instantiating these objects correctly? when I pause debugger on the object it appears to have the entire observable .viewProperties, but as soon as it goes to the dom it doesnt know what it is, what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it this way then the code should work without any errors. Check your `ko.applyBindings()` call - maybe you have an error there.

```js
var createViewProperties = function () {
        return {
            rightContentVisibility: ko.observable(true) // normally false, true for testing
        };
    };

var data = [
   {
     headline: "Are you interested in helping others?",
     viewProperties: new createViewProperties(),
   },
   {
     headline: "This is a second modal view",
     viewProperties: new createViewProperties(),
   }
];

ko.applyBindings({ currentView: data });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="with: currentView">
     <div data-bind="css: $data.headline" class="cover-img"></div>
     <div data-bind="$data.viewProperties.rightContentVisibility"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is because you are calling `createViewProperties` with the `new` keyword. Using `new` before a method call in JavaScript sets the context of `this` to the current function and implicitly return `this` from that function. Remove `new` from your call to `createViewProperties` and everything should work.

```
var data = [
 {
    headline: "Are you interested in helping others?",
    viewProperties: createViewProperties(),
 },
 {
    headline: "This is a second modal view",
    viewProperties: createViewProperties(),
 }
];
```

**EDIT**

Alternatively you can use `new` like this:

```
var createViewProperties = function () {
       this.rightContentVisibility = ko.observable(true);       
};
```

Then new it up the way you've been doing it all along. Note that convention is to use an uppercase character in JavaScript for method names which are called with the `new` keyword. The name of the 'constructor' method is also usually a noun as in object oriented languages. So something better would be

```
var ViewProperties = function() { /* etc etc */ };
```

That said, there's nothing wrong with returning an anonymous object like you're doing instead.